# Remove extra annotation ns2 using NamespacePrefixMapper

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling

I want to remove extra annotation ns2 in the xml generated by marshal using NamespacePrefixMapper class instead of using package-info.java file.

My code is as below:

Req class:

```
package com.example;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(propOrder = { "password", "title", "firstName", "lastName", "email"})

@XmlRootElement

public class Req {

  private String password;
  private String title;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;

  @XmlElement(name= "Password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
 public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@XmlElement(name= "Title")
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
@XmlElement(name= "FirstName")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
@XmlElement(name= "LastName")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@XmlElement(name= "Email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

PreferredMapper class:

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;

public class PreferredMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper{

    private static final String URI ="http://schema.bsi.ib.example/service/request/v1";

    @Override
        public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {

        if(URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
            return "";
        } 

        return suggestion;
    }
        @Override
        public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris() {
            return new String[] { URI };
        }

}
```

Test class:

```
package com.example;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import com.example.Req;
import com.example.PreferredMapper;
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JAXBException
    {

        setRequest("Tiger123", "Miss","Rose","Crocker","hello@world.com");

    }

    public static void setRequest(String passWord, String title, String firstName, String lastName,String email) throws JAXBException
    {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Req.class);

        Req ibw=new Req();

        ibw.setEmail(email);
        ibw.setPassword(passWord);
        ibw.setTitle(title);
        ibw.setFirstName(firstName);
        ibw.setLastName(lastName);

        JAXBElement<Req> element=new JAXBElement<Req> (new QName("http://schema.bsi.ib.example/service/request/v1","CustomerProfile"),Req.class,ibw);
        Marshaller m=context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
        m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new PreferredMapper());

        m.marshal(element, System.out);

    }   
}
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:CustomerProfile xmlns:ns2="http://schema.bsi.ib.example/service/request/v1">
    <Password>Tiger123</Password>
    <Title>Miss</Title>
    <FirstName>Rose</FirstName>
    <LastName>Crocker</LastName>
    <Email>hello@world.com</Email>
</ns2:CustomerProfile>
```

not able to remove ns2 with above code please help

Comment: Do you have a reason for not being able to do this with a package-info annotation?

Comment: no i am able to do with package-info annotation i want to do with namespaceprefixmapper also

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to "remove ns2" but keep the XML the same semantically then you'd end up with something like

```
<CustomerProfile xmlns="http://schema.bsi.ib.example/service/request/v1">
    <Password xmlns="">Tiger123</Password>
    <Title xmlns="">Miss</Title>
```

because currently only the CustomerProfile element is in a namespace, its children are not. Remember that the prefix mappings you suggest in your mapper are only that - suggestions - and the marshaller may ignore them if it thinks they are inappropriate.

I presume you're resisting modifying the `package-info` because you want to generate everything from an existing `.xsd`.  Are you in a position to modify this schema and add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the `<xs:schema>` element?  If you can do that then

```
<CustomerProfile xmlns="http://schema.bsi.ib.example/service/request/v1">
    <Password>Tiger123</Password>
    <Title>Miss</Title>
```

(without the `xmlns=""`) would become valid and your existing mapper may start to work.

If you *can't* modify the schema then you probably don't want to use a default namespace on the `CustomerProfile` anyway...

Comment: i cannot give elementFormDefault ="qualified" in @Xmlschema as i dont want to use package-info.java file